# fixing loop structure for generating tokens

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

Trying to generate a number of tokens after the function reads a string.

The program is a part of lexical analyzer for HTML, i am just trying to figure out the logic first.

For a string like:  String: "Heading goes here< /=>heading"
output should be: TEXT LANGLE SLASH EQUAL SLASH TEXT END

Meaning anything outside the before <> is considered one text token. When i am inside <, i have other cases. When the string ends, an END token is generated

My problem is, the program is stuck in an endless loops of END tokens. I know i am making some stupid mistake, but i can figure it out for the life of me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void gettoken()
{
    string wordin="there you were<=/>there";

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < wordin.length(); )
    {

        if(wordin.at(i)== '<') 
        {
            cout<<("LANGLE")<<endl;
            i++;
            {
                if(wordin.at(i)== '=') 
                {
                    i++;
                    cout<<("EQUAL")<<endl;
                }

                if(wordin.at(i)== '/')
                {
                    i++;
                    cout<<("SLASH")<<endl;
                }

                if(wordin.at(i)== '>')
                {
                    i++;
                    cout<<("RANGLE")<<endl;
                }


            } // internal LANGLE ends here

        }

        else if (isalpha(wordin[i])) {
            unsigned int j=wordin.find('<') ;
            i=j;

            cout<<"TEXT"<<endl;}

        }
        cout<<"END"<<endl;

    }


int main()
{
    gettoken();
}
```

Update:
I fixed the code somewhat, now its generating TEXT LANGLE SLASH EQUAL LANGLE TEXT LANGLE SLASH EQUAL LANGLE and so on where it should be like  TEXT LANGLE SLASH EQUAL LANGLE TEXT END..can someone help me out with how to properly terminate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a i++ in your else statement (the one outputing "END"). This causes the endless loop.

Using a debugger would have been faster than using stackoverflow in this case.

Your code had many other issues. Consider:
- Using smart indentation, else, it's very hard to read
- Use a debugger to figure out what't wrong instead of posting the code to stackoverflow...;-)

Here is a working, AND readable, code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void gettoken()
{
    string wordin="there you were<=/>there";

    bool inTag = false;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < wordin.size(); )
    {
        if(wordin.at(i)== '<') 
        {
            cout<<("LANGLE")<<endl;
            i++;
            inTag = true;
        }
        else if ( inTag && wordin.at(i)== '=' ) 
        {
            i++;
            cout<<("EQUAL")<<endl; 
        }
        else if ( inTag && wordin.at(i)== '/' )
        {
            i++;
            cout<<("SLASH")<<endl;
        }
        else if ( inTag && wordin.at(i)== '>' )
        {
            i++;
            cout<<("RANGLE")<<endl; 
            inTag = false;
        }
        else if (isalpha(wordin[i])) 
        {
            unsigned int j = wordin.find('<',i) ;
            if ( j == std::string::npos )
            {
                i = wordin.size(); // move to end of string position
            }
            else
            {
                i=j;
                cout<<"TEXT"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"END"<<endl; 
}


int main()

{
    gettoken();
}
```

It outputs:

```
TEXT
LANGLE
EQUAL
SLASH
RANGLE
TEXT
END
```

Hopefully, this is what you wanted...

Comment: well, now its giving me an endless stream of text and end tokens which is clearly wrong. I am just looking for help to make sure the logic i am using here is sound, debugger cant help with that.

Comment: Thanks ! how does one use smart indentation. Sorry for the trouble tho, i haven't used stack exchange a lot before.

Comment: There is a problem with your code, /= can only happen inside <>. Hence i put a loop inside < loop, which checks for / and = and terminates the < statement after it reaches >.

Comment: Just indent your code correctly, as propopsed, have all related if/else aligned

Comment: Ok. is there any function i can use instead of isalpha, that helps output anything outside <> as text, including characters,digits and spaces

Comment: You had no loop inside the first one, just a { } statement. Please, write your code with better indentation to have it more readable and try to fix it.

Comment: Here you are, added inTag boolean to check we are inside a < > "group"

Comment: still having trouble reading text just outside of <>. Like for "there" it gave me just an END token instead of TEXT END. Also, why won't it read Text after < >, like "</=>there" generates LANGLE SLASH EQUAL RANGLE END and nothing for there

Comment: Once again (and last), running a debugger in step by step will answer the question

Comment: I appreciate all the help sir.